# Lint - MissingTranslation - Where to store language independent strings

Tags: android, string, lint

Hi i have an Icon font in my android application, for this i have defined some strings like this

```
<string name="icon_bottom_button_map">&#xF10F;</string>
<string name="icon_bottom_button_keyboard">&#xF10A;</string>
<string name="icon_bottom_button_service">&#xF111;</string>
```

but lint plots the error "MissingTranslation"

Where should i store these language independent strings?

Comment: Define in java constant class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to ignore, but you can do it like this:

```
<string name="hello" translatable="false">hello</string>
```

or

you can insert following code in the lint.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    ...

    <issue
        id="MissingTranslation"
        severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

good luck